# sqlplus query with comment giving duplicate rows

Tags: oracle, duplicates, output, rows, sqlplus

Updating my question: 
When I run this query from unix using sqplus it gives me duplicate outputs
Query:

```
select sysdate from dual
/
/*comment*/
EXIT
```

Output

```
SQL> @tt.sql

12-AUG-16

12-AUG-16
```

Comment: Just a hunch: try replacing the `/`s with `;`s.

Comment: dont get it. why is it displaying two rows ?

Comment: How do you run that "from unix using sqlplus"? I just tested by copying your code and pasting it directly in SQLPlus, and as expected, when execution got to the EXIT line, it shut down my SQLPlus window (it exited, as the name implies) - execution never got to the second /, which in SQLPlus means "repeat the last action" (and explains the second row perfectly). Are you sure you didn't have the EXIT line commented out?

Comment: Yes I ran it from unix. And even if I remove the last slash (after EXIT), it is giving duplicate lines.

Comment: What do you mean "ran it from unix" - especially, what do you mean by "ran"? Did you simply type the lines in the SQLPlus window one by one? Do you have a script which you are running? Did you copy from a text editor and paste in the SQLPlus window? HOW are you running it?

Comment: Actually, sorry, never mind - I see your output, you ran it from a sql script. I'll try it that way.

Comment: Alright, I created a script with exactly what you posted, and it EXITS the session, it does not produce the two lines you show. Are you sure that is the EXACT content of your script? Oh, I see it is NOT after your edit.

Comment: @mathguy its showing two outputs even after removing the last slash

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120815/discussion-between-shitu-and-mathguy).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what is happening.

The first two lines (including the /) form a complete SQL statement. SQLPlus executes it and displays the first line.

Then /*comment*/ is OUTSIDE the SQL statement. So it is interpreted by SQLPlus, not as a SQL comment.

The point is, comments in the SQLPlus scripting language have a different syntax; they are lines that begin with REM[ARK]. /*comment*/ is NOT a comment in SQLPlus.

Instead, in SQLPlus, a slash / as the first character on a new line means repeat the last SQL command (if after that you had SQLPlus commands, like DESCRIBE or COLUMN, those are ignored). Everything AFTER the slash is ignored. To convince yourself of this, try again, but with the comment line changed to /*comment*   (delete the second slash). You will see the same result.

Then you have the command EXIT, but since it is NOT followed by a slash, it is not seen as a completed command. If I copy and paste your code in my SQLPlus window, I get the screenshot below. However, if at this point you press ENTER (or if this was in a sql script and not copied and pasted from a text editor), the SQLPlus window would shut down.

Hope this helps!

```
SQL> select sysdate from dual
  2  /

SYSDATE
----------
2016-08-12

1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> /*comment*/

SYSDATE
----------
2016-08-12

1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
SQL> EXIT
```